# Can someone explain why I can’t post?

Tags: support, answer-quality

I’m guessing I either had answers deleted a long time ago to the point of me not being able to pull them up & not knowing I might be able to revise them & not have them count against me. Also I did not know a deleted answer can hurt me.

Also it’s possible that my answers could have been seen as too self promoting as I have explicitly answered questions that relate to a project/app that I’ve spent several months, if not a few years, creating. (Despite that unless my project directly answers the question I don’t spam this forum or any other - still I assume the algorithms used to keep the site clean have very low tolerances for reasons.)

Comment: Have a look through https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you've hit [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans), so I would recommend following its advice.  Looking at your account, I do see evidence that a couple of your answers were flagged as spam, since they linked to a project without much more explanation or claim of affiliation; an excerpt from the Help Center's [How to not be a spammer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), which I recommend you read in full:

> However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

While looking at your account, I would recommend earning an easy badge ("Informed") by hitting [our site's tour page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), just to make sure you're familiar with the site's recommendations and policies.

Comment: I have read it in full and multiple times at this point. I mentioned it only for historical reasons, and as far as I know I have not ran afoul of those rules since it was brought to my attention as it was never done purposefully or with any intention of spamming these forums.

Regardless I am still dealing with some fall out for one reason or another.

Comment: It does look like those answers were deleted after being downvoted. As you can imagine, people react strongly to spam around here, and downvoting is one way to get rid of it. Since your posts aren't actually spam, if you can rework them to stay inside the guidelines, they stand a chance of being un-downvoted and/or up-voted. Please take care to explain how the OP would use the project (download/install/configure/run) to solve their problem, as well as claim affiliation.

Comment: I don't mind reworking them one bit, if the visibility to them could be restored for me, but I am assuming they were deleted over 60 days ago and I no longer have the ability to see that far back myself.

My project/app has even become much easier to configure/explain, and so I was actually looking to go back and update a number of posts & have actually updated some, but not all, on other exchange forums. I was awfully verbose in some of my posts, so much of that was going to go away with the simpler revisions.

Comment: Great! I admit I don't have a full grasp on all the details of the S.E. UI, so I wasn't sure if you could see them or not. If you go to your profile, then go to the textbox towards the top that contains "user:393552" and you append (space) and "deleted:yes" does that help? They were indeed deleted more than 60 days ago.  Or, [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10721/copy-pasting-in-gnome-terminal/566192#566192) and [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114392/copy-paste-in-a-terminal-without-shift/566184#566184).

Comment: Thank you for providing those links, as they indeed do not show up for me even when I search for them using those parameters you mention. I will attempt to revise those 2 posts.

Surprisingly they were both short responses lol. I think I was demoralized at the time from having criticisms on my verbosity around the time I had posted those, not in these forums but over at askubuntu. I'll be more concise though in the revisions, assuming they go through ok.

Comment: The 2 posts are both locked, so apparently I cannot revise them :/. One of them definitely needs mentioning of xkeysnail and the other.. well I could take the ego out of it no doubt and provide a little more info. Since those posts I've also learned to never link to the shorter url of my own project and just use the github link. Seems to trigger the automated system, whether people think I properly disclosed my affiliation or not, which of course I make sure is clear now.

Comment: My apologies for not seeing it earlier; they *were* locked; I've now unlocked them. Please feel free to ping me here again after your edits, so that I can review them and clear the existing flags. Thanks!